# BIP 38 Implementions for Altcoins?

Tags: wallet, security, api, bip38

Trying to identify implementations for creating BIP 38 encrypted private keys for alternative coins to spark collaborative open source discussions to standardize BIP 38 to support altcoins. Please share any BIP 38 implementation URLs you are aware of that support one or more altcoins for investigative purposes.

Comment: Ran across [LTC](https://bitcoinpaperwallet.com/bitcoinpaperwallet/generate-wallet.html?design=alt-litecoin#) generator, but prefix is locked 6P.

Answer (score 2):

The most capable working implementation for extending BIP 38 to altcoins (having strong Bitcoin heritage) is provided by bitcoin-explorer's (bx) [Key Encryption Commands](https://github.com/libbitcoin/libbitcoin/wiki/Altcoin-Version-Mappings#bx---key-encryption-commands) (with working examples applied to Dash) that supports **both** [BIP 38 modes](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0038.mediawiki#specification):

#### 1. AES256Encrypt, AES256Decrypt - a paper wallet use case

#### 2. EC Multiply - a Casascius use case

A backwardly compatible [Proposal](https://github.com/libbitcoin/libbitcoin/wiki/Altchain-Encrypted-Private-Keys#proposal) and a [Table](https://github.com/libbitcoin/libbitcoin/wiki/Altchain-Encrypted-Private-Keys#sample-map) are provided to have deterministic leading base58check encoded characters, apart from the "6P" allocated to Bitcoin, to distinguish BIP 38 encrypted keys from those belonging to different altcoin blockchains. See the [BIP 44 Altcoin Version Mapping Table](https://github.com/libbitcoin/libbitcoin/wiki/Altcoin-Version-Mappings#bip44-altcoin-version-mapping-table) to apply proposed BIP 38 extension to support cryptocurrencies other than Bitcoin (BTC). Also worth examining the [BIP 38 Security Considerations](https://github.com/libbitcoin/libbitcoin/wiki/BIP38-Security-Considerations) wiki page.